# Is Mahamaham connected with kumbh mela?

Tags: festivals, kumbh-mela

Mahamaham is celebrated every 12 years at Kumbakonam, when people take a dip in the holy mahamaham tank.  Does this also qualify as a kumbha mela?  What is its scriptural background?

Answer (score 2):

Kumbhkonam was called the "southern counterpart" to the Kumbh Mela in *Alphabetical List of the Feasts and Holidays of the Hindus and Muhammadans* from the Imperial Record Department, Kolkata in 1914.

Sorry, but beyond this I could not find information.

Comment: When there is no consensus on using emojis, you should not use them. It looks like a box to me. I have no intention of downloading a webfont just to look at the emoji you have used. It slows my browser and system. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZhnI.png

Comment: Because you cannot see, you would deny everyone from seeing?

Comment: @RubelliteFae Its fine. Keep using unless there is no consensus as there is no consensus for either side.

Comment: Answer is enough. Emoji is not needed and adds nothing to the answer. Giving description of the emoji is unnecessary. It would be good if you add anything more useful resource in the answer. It is not only me. It is many hundreds who use the same browser. It depends on the browser. What does the emoji add in the answer?

Comment: In a single character it expresses "I tried to find more information, but could not and so I am disappointed." It's called economy of words. You can express much in a single image. If they were useless, then when the Japanese invented emoji no one would have used them. But they were so heavily used that Japanese people would not buy an iPhone unless it had emoji. So Apple added it and now everyone has emoji. Which browser does not have them?

Comment: It is not only me. There are hundreds of them who see the site. There are many browsers from open source which are against apple and don't support emojis. Chrome also doesn't support webfont with emojis. I have no intention to get a emoji pack from an external source to read a single character from your answer. Answers should be very clear so that it doesn't need any clarification from external side or from the author. It is happening now. If you continue, it will go on in future too. If its's economy of words, take time to write a comment of 100 words every time. It is better not to use.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187520/displaying-emojis-in-old-browsers All browsers support them, but the problem is your font library. This means you are using an unsupported version of Windows because all currently supported versions Segoe fonts. Or maybe you are using some version of Linux in which case you should be used to doing things the hard way.

Comment: The same post says I should download a font. I don't want to download a webfont just to look at an emoji. It wastes space on my browser, my system. I prefer not to. I have more important programs to install on my browser. That is external help. Answers should be clear to all the browsers and users not based on the browser they use. We are not a programming site to get all the stuff updated. Just remove the emoji. Problem will be solved. Other SE sites also don't allow emojis. Why should we be different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75961/discussion-between-rubellite-fae-and-sarvabhouma).

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer does it qualify as “kumbha mela” would be necessary to understand the properties or meaning of some event to qualify as a kumbha mela. Definition of kumbha mela. But it would be entirely different issue. However, if we look at “kumbha mela” as certain brand name and event protected by UNESCO, Mahamaham does not qualify, it is in a different place and called “Kumbha Mela of the South” oftenly.
If we look at the aspect of origin and spiritual effect or importance it definitely qualifies. Origin is related to “kumbha” what is the holy pot of Amrita. It is involved in Mahamaham and Kumbh Mela. There is an astrological connection too. Mahamaham as one of the kumbha melas is in Maghā Nakshatra. Kumbakonam is a sacred place of great importance on its own rights. I would say that what you seek in Kumbha Mela you would find and achieve in Mahamaham (“Kumbha Mela of the South”).
To paraphrase from http://mahakumbhfestival.com : It provides us this great opportunity to purify our soul by bathing in holy water  and serving saints.
[Kumbh mela south](http://www.sanskritimagazine.com/events-festivals/masi-mahamagha-great-kumbh-mela-south/)
[Wiki - Mahamaham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahamaham)